# PyTorch slice matrix with vector

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

Say I have one matrix and one vector as follows:

```py
import torch
x = torch.tensor([[1, 2, 3],
                  [4, 5, 6],
                  [7, 8, 9]])

y = torch.tensor([0, 2, 1])
```

is there a way to slice it `x[y]` so the result is:

```py
res = [1, 6, 8]
```

So basically I take the first element of `y` and take the element in `x` that corresponds to the first row and the elements' column.

Comment: Added brackets in definition of `x`, not sure if it was just a typo here or also in your code.

Comment: it was a typo, thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can specify the corresponding row index as:

```py
import torch
x = torch.tensor([[1, 2, 3],
                  [4, 5, 6],
                  [7, 8, 9]])

y = torch.tensor([0, 2, 1])

x[range(x.shape[0]), y]
tensor([1, 6, 8])
```

Comment: thanks for the fast reply, i get the following error:


TypeError: only integer tensors of a single element can be converted to an index

Comment: Im able to reproduce this answer withough any problem. Please revise your question @yarin

Comment: sorry i accidentally mistyped the parenthesis, now it works

Comment: Good! it's simpler than torch.gather().

Comment: Thanks, it works, but note that the "y" tensor has to be of type `LongTensor`.

Answer (score 4):

Advanced indexing in pytorch works just as `NumPy's`, i.e the indexing arrays are broadcast together across the axes. So you could do as in FBruzzesi's answer.

Though similarly to `np.take_along_axis`, in pytorch you also have [`torch.gather`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.gather), to take values along a specific axis:

```
x.gather(1, y.view(-1,1)).view(-1)
# tensor([1, 6, 8])
```